# What is the notation for separable states or independent variables?

Tags: probability, notation, quantum-mechanics

Is there any specific notation that two quantum states are separable or that two random variables are independent?

Answer (score 1):

As general the question is, the answer can be; in general, on separability of quantum states one implies certain separability criteria for orthogonality of such. In terms of details and also notation please find

[here>>>](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0795) - see for instance equation 2

and on Quantiki

[here>>>](http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Separability_criteria)